# How to setup a mongodb grafana dashboard using helm bitnami/mongodb and kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I have the helm chart mongodb installed on my k8s cluster (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb).

I also have kube-prometheus-stack installed on my k8s cluster. (https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack)

I've setup a grafana dashboard for mongodb which should pull in data from a prometheus data source. (https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/2583 )

However, my grafana dashboard is empty with no data.

[image]

**I'm wondering if i have not configured something with the helm chart properly. Please see the mongodb helm chart below.**

[image]

**mognodb chart.yml**

```
## Global Docker image parameters
## Please, note that this will override the image parameters, including dependencies, configured to use the global value
## Current available global Docker image parameters: imageRegistry and imagePullSecrets
##
global:
#   imageRegistry: myRegistryName
#   imagePullSecrets:
#     - myRegistryKeySecretName
#   storageClass: myStorageClass
## Override the namespace for resource deployed by the chart, but can itself be overridden by the local namespaceOverride
  namespaceOverride: mongodb

image:
  ## Bitnami MongoDB registry
  ##
  registry: docker.io
  ## Bitnami MongoDB image name
  ##
  repository: bitnami/mongodb
  ## Bitnami MongoDB image tag
  ## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb/tags/
  ##
  tag: 4.4.1-debian-10-r13
  ## Specify a imagePullPolicy
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
  ##
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
  ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
  ##
  # pullSecrets:
  #   - myRegistryKeySecretName

  ## Set to true if you would like to see extra information on logs
  ## It turns on Bitnami debugging in minideb-extras-base
  ## ref:  https://github.com/bitnami/minideb-extras-base
  debug: false

## String to partially override mongodb.fullname template (will maintain the release name)
##
# nameOverride:

## String to fully override mongodb.fullname template
##
# fullnameOverride:

## Kubernetes Cluster Domain
##
clusterDomain: cluster.local

## Use an alternate scheduler, e.g. "stork".
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
# schedulerName:

## MongoDB architecture. Allowed values: standalone or replicaset
##
architecture: replicaset

## Use StatefulSet instead of Deployment when deploying standalone
##
useStatefulSet: false

## MongoDB Authentication parameters
##
auth:
  ## Enable authentication
  ## ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/
  ##
  enabled: true
  ## MongoDB root password
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/blob/master/README.md#setting-the-root-password-on-first-run
  ##
  rootPassword: "<redacted>"
  ## MongoDB custom user and database
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/blob/master/README.md#creating-a-user-and-database-on-first-run
  ##
  # username: username
  # password: password
  # database: database
  ## Key used for replica set authentication
  ## Ignored when mongodb.architecture=standalone
  ##
  replicaSetKey: <redacted>

  ## Existing secret with MongoDB credentials
  ## NOTE: When it's set the previous parameters are ignored.
  ##
  # existingSecret: name-of-existing-secret

## Name of the replica set
## Ignored when mongodb.architecture=standalone
##
replicaSetName: rs0

## Enable DNS hostnames in the replica set config
## Ignored when mongodb.architecture=standalone
## Ignored when externalAccess.enabled=true
##
replicaSetHostnames: true

## Whether enable/disable IPv6 on MongoDB
## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/blob/master/README.md#enabling/disabling-ipv6
##
enableIPv6: false

## Whether enable/disable DirectoryPerDB on MongoDB
## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/blob/master/README.md#enabling/disabling-directoryperdb
##
directoryPerDB: false

## MongoDB System Log configuration
## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb#configuring-system-log-verbosity-level
##
systemLogVerbosity: 0
disableSystemLog: false

## MongoDB configuration file for Primary and Secondary nodes. For documentation of all options, see:
##   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
## Example:
## configuration:
##   # where and how to store data.
##   storage:
##     dbPath: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db
##     journal:
##       enabled: true
##     directoryPerDB: false
##   # where to write logging data
##   systemLog:
##     destination: file
##     quiet: false
##     logAppend: true
##     logRotate: reopen
##     path: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log
##     verbosity: 0
##   # network interfaces
##   net:
##     port: 27017
##     unixDomainSocket:
##       enabled: true
##       pathPrefix: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp
##     ipv6: false
##     bindIpAll: true
##   # replica set options
##   #replication:
##     #replSetName: replicaset
##     #enableMajorityReadConcern: true
##   # process management options
##   processManagement:
##      fork: false
##      pidFilePath: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid
##   # set parameter options
##   setParameter:
##      enableLocalhostAuthBypass: true
##   # security options
##   security:
##     authorization: disabled
##     #keyFile: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/keyfile
##
configuration: ""

## ConfigMap with MongoDB configuration for Primary and Secondary nodes
## NOTE: When it's set the arbiter.configuration parameter is ignored
##
# existingConfigmap:

## initdb scripts
## Specify dictionary of scripts to be run at first boot
## Example:
## initdbScripts:
##   my_init_script.sh: |
##      #!/bin/bash
##      echo "Do something."
initdbScripts: {}

## Existing ConfigMap with custom init scripts
##
# initdbScriptsConfigMap:

## Command and args for running the container (set to default if not set). Use array form
##
# command:
# args:

## Additional command line flags
## Example:
## extraFlags:
##  - "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2"
##
extraFlags: []

## Additional environment variables to set
## E.g:
## extraEnvVars:
##   - name: FOO
##     value: BAR
##
extraEnvVars: []

## ConfigMap with extra environment variables
##
# extraEnvVarsCM:

## Secret with extra environment variables
##
# extraEnvVarsSecret:

## Annotations to be added to the MongoDB statefulset. Evaluated as a template.
##
annotations: {}

## Additional labels to be added to the MongoDB statefulset. Evaluated as a template.
##
labels: {}

## Number of MongoDB replicas to deploy.
## Ignored when mongodb.architecture=standalone
##
replicaCount: 1

## StrategyType for MongoDB statefulset
## It can be set to RollingUpdate or Recreate by default.
##
strategyType: RollingUpdate

## MongoDB should be initialized one by one when building the replicaset for the first time.
##
podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady

## Affinity for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
##
affinity: {}

## Node labels for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
##
nodeSelector: {}

## Tolerations for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
##
tolerations: []

## Lables for MongoDB pods. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/
##
podLabels: {}

## Annotations for MongoDB pods. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/
##
podAnnotations: {}

## MongoDB pods' priority.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/
##
# priorityClassName: ""

## MongoDB pods' Security Context.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod
##
podSecurityContext:
  enabled: true
  fsGroup: 1001
  ## sysctl settings
  ## Example:
  ## sysctls:
  ## - name: net.core.somaxconn
  ##   value: "10000"
  ##
  sysctls: []

## MongoDB containers' Security Context (main and metrics container).
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container
##
containerSecurityContext:
  enabled: true
  runAsUser: 1001
  runAsNonRoot: true

## MongoDB containers' resource requests and limits.
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
##
resources:
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  limits: {}
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  requests: {}
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

## MongoDB pods' liveness and readiness probes. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes
##
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 6
  successThreshold: 1
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 6
  successThreshold: 1

## Custom Liveness probes for MongoDB pods
##
customLivenessProbe: {}

## Custom Rediness probes MongoDB pods
##
customReadinessProbe: {}

## Add init containers to the MongoDB pods.
## Example:
## initContainers:
##   - name: your-image-name
##     image: your-image
##     imagePullPolicy: Always
##     ports:
##       - name: portname
##         containerPort: 1234
##
initContainers: {}

## Add sidecars to the MongoDB pods.
## Example:
## sidecars:
##   - name: your-image-name
##     image: your-image
##     imagePullPolicy: Always
##     ports:
##       - name: portname
##         containerPort: 1234
##
sidecars: {}

## extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts allows you to mount other volumes on MongoDB pods
## Examples:
## extraVolumeMounts:
##   - name: extras
##     mountPath: /usr/share/extras
##     readOnly: true
## extraVolumes:
##   - name: extras
##     emptyDir: {}
extraVolumeMounts: []
extraVolumes: []

## MongoDB Pod Disruption Budget configuration
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/
##
pdb:
  create: true
  ## Min number of pods that must still be available after the eviction
  ##
  minAvailable: 1
  ## Max number of pods that can be unavailable after the eviction
  ##
  # maxUnavailable: 1

## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
##
persistence:
  enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  ## Ignored when mongodb.architecture=replicaset
  ##
  # existingClaim:
  ## PV Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ## set, choosing the default provisioner.
  ##
  # storageClass: "-"
  ## PV Access Mode
  ##
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  ## PVC size
  ##
  size: 50Gi
  ## PVC annotations
  ##
  annotations: {}
  ## The path the volume will be mounted at, useful when using different
  ## MongoDB images.
  ##
  mountPath: /bitnami/mongodb
  ## The subdirectory of the volume to mount to, useful in dev environments
  ## and one PV for multiple services.
  ##
  subPath: ""

## Service parameters
##
service:
  ## Service type
  ##
  type: ClusterIP
  ## MongoDB service port
  ##
  port: 27017
  ## MongoDB service port name
  ##
  portName: mongodb
  ## Specify the nodePort value for the LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport
  ##
  nodePort: ""
  ## MongoDB service clusterIP IP
  ##
  # clusterIP: None
  ## Specify the externalIP value ClusterIP service type.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips
  ##
  externalIPs: []
  ## Specify the loadBalancerIP value for LoadBalancer service types.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer
  ##
  # loadBalancerIP:
  ## Specify the loadBalancerSourceRanges value for LoadBalancer service types.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service
  ##
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  ## Provide any additional annotations which may be required. Evaluated as a template
  ##
  annotations: {}

## External Access to MongoDB nodes configuration
##
externalAccess:
  ## Enable Kubernetes external cluster access to MongoDB nodes
  ##
  enabled: true
  ## External IPs auto-discovery configuration
  ## An init container is used to auto-detect LB IPs or node ports by querying the K8s API
  ## Note: RBAC might be required
  ##
  autoDiscovery:
    ## Enable external IP/ports auto-discovery
    ##
    enabled: true
    ## Bitnami Kubectl image
    ## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl/tags/
    ##
    image:
      registry: docker.io
      repository: bitnami/kubectl
      tag: 1.18.9-debian-10-r4
      ## Specify a imagePullPolicy
      ## Defaults to 'Always' if image tag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
      ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
      ##
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets (secrets must be manually created in the namespace)
      ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
      ## Example:
      ## pullSecrets:
      ##   - myRegistryKeySecretName
      ##
      pullSecrets: []
    ## Init Container resource requests and limits
    ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
    ##
    resources:
      # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
      # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
      # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
      # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
      limits: {}
      #   cpu: 100m
      #   memory: 128Mi
      requests: {}
      #   cpu: 100m
      #   memory: 128Mi
  ## Parameters to configure K8s service(s) used to externally access MongoDB
  ## A new service per broker will be created
  ##
  service:
    ## Service type. Allowed values: LoadBalancer or NodePort
    ##
    type: LoadBalancer
    ## Port used when service type is LoadBalancer
    ##
    port: 27017
    ## Array of load balancer IPs for each MongoDB node. Length must be the same as replicaCount
    ## Example:
    ## loadBalancerIPs:
    ##   - X.X.X.X
    ##   - Y.Y.Y.Y
    ##
    loadBalancerIPs: []
    ## Load Balancer sources
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service
    ## Example:
    ## loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    ## - 10.10.10.0/24
    ##
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
    ## Array of node ports used for each MongoDB node. Length must be the same as replicaCount
    ## Example:
    ## nodePorts:
    ##   - 30001
    ##   - 30002
    ##
    nodePorts: []
    ## When service type is NodePort, you can specify the domain used for MongoDB advertised hostnames.
    ## If not specified, the container will try to get the kubernetes node external IP
    ##
    # domain: mydomain.com
    ## Provide any additional annotations which may be required. Evaluated as a template
    ##
    annotations: {}

##
## MongoDB Arbiter parameters.
##
arbiter:
  ## Enable deploying the MongoDB Arbiter
  ##   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/
  enabled: true

  ## MongoDB configuration file for the Arbiter. For documentation of all options, see:
  ##   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
  ##
  configuration: ""

  ## ConfigMap with MongoDB configuration for the Arbiter
  ## NOTE: When it's set the arbiter.configuration parameter is ignored
  ##
  # existingConfigmap:

  ## Command and args for running the container (set to default if not set). Use array form
  ##
  # command:
  # args:

  ## Additional command line flags
  ## Example:
  ## extraFlags:
  ##  - "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2"
  ##
  extraFlags: []

  ## Additional environment variables to set
  ## E.g:
  ## extraEnvVars:
  ##   - name: FOO
  ##     value: BAR
  ##
  extraEnvVars: []

  ## ConfigMap with extra environment variables
  ##
  # extraEnvVarsCM:

  ## Secret with extra environment variables
  ##
  # extraEnvVarsSecret:

  ## Annotations to be added to the Arbiter statefulset. Evaluated as a template.
  ##
  annotations: {}

  ## Additional to be added to the Arbiter statefulset. Evaluated as a template.
  ##
  labels: {}

  ## Affinity for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
  ##
  affinity: {}

  ## Node labels for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
  ##
  nodeSelector: {}

  ## Tolerations for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  ##
  tolerations: []

  ## Lables for MongoDB Arbiter pods. Evaluated as a template.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/
  ##
  podLabels: {}

  ## Annotations for MongoDB Arbiter pods. Evaluated as a template.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/
  ##
  podAnnotations: {}

  ## MongoDB Arbiter pods' priority.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/
  ##
  # priorityClassName: ""

  ## MongoDB Arbiter pods' Security Context.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod
  ##
  podSecurityContext:
    enabled: true
    fsGroup: 1001
    ## sysctl settings
    ## Example:
    ## sysctls:
    ## - name: net.core.somaxconn
    ##   value: "10000"
    ##
    sysctls: []

  ## MongoDB Arbiter containers' Security Context (only main container).
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container
  ##
  containerSecurityContext:
    enabled: true
    runAsUser: 1001

  ## MongoDB Arbiter containers' resource requests and limits.
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  resources:
    # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
    # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
    # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
    # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
    limits: {}
    #   cpu: 100m
    #   memory: 128Mi
    requests: {}
    #   cpu: 100m
    #   memory: 128Mi

  ## MongoDB Arbiter pods' liveness and readiness probes. Evaluated as a template.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes
  ##
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    periodSeconds: 10
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 6
    successThreshold: 1
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 10
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 6
    successThreshold: 1

  ## Custom Liveness probes for MongoDB Arbiter pods
  ##
  customLivenessProbe: {}

  ## Custom Rediness probes MongoDB Arbiter pods
  ##
  customReadinessProbe: {}

  ## Add init containers to the MongoDB Arbiter pods.
  ## Example:
  ## initContainers:
  ##   - name: your-image-name
  ##     image: your-image
  ##     imagePullPolicy: Always
  ##     ports:
  ##       - name: portname
  ##         containerPort: 1234
  ##
  initContainers: {}

  ## Add sidecars to the MongoDB Arbiter pods.
  ## Example:
  ## sidecars:
  ##   - name: your-image-name
  ##     image: your-image
  ##     imagePullPolicy: Always
  ##     ports:
  ##       - name: portname
  ##         containerPort: 1234
  ##
  sidecars: {}

  ## extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts allows you to mount other volumes on MongoDB Arbiter pods
  ## Examples:
  ## extraVolumeMounts:
  ##   - name: extras
  ##     mountPath: /usr/share/extras
  ##     readOnly: true
  ## extraVolumes:
  ##   - name: extras
  ##     emptyDir: {}
  extraVolumeMounts: []
  extraVolumes: []

  ## MongoDB Arbiter Pod Disruption Budget configuration
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/
  ##
  pdb:
    create: false
    ## Min number of pods that must still be available after the eviction
    ##
    minAvailable: 1
    ## Max number of pods that can be unavailable after the eviction
    ##
    # maxUnavailable: 1

## ServiceAccount
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/
##
serviceAccount:
  ## Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  ##
  create: true
  ## The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  ## If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the rabbitmq.fullname template
  ##
  # name:

## Role Based Access
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/
##
rbac:
  ## Specifies whether RBAC rules should be created
  ## binding MongoDB ServiceAccount to a role
  ## that allows MongoDB pods querying the K8s API
  ##
  create: true

## Init Container paramaters
## Change the owner and group of the persistent volume(s) mountpoint(s) to 'runAsUser:fsGroup' on each component
## values from the securityContext section of the component
##
volumePermissions:
  enabled: false
  ## Bitnami Minideb image
  ## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/minideb/tags/
  ##
  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/minideb
    tag: buster
    ## Specify a imagePullPolicy
    ## Defaults to 'Always' if image tag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
    ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
    ##
    pullPolicy: Always
    ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets (secrets must be manually created in the namespace)
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
    ## Example:
    ## pullSecrets:
    ##   - myRegistryKeySecretName
    ##
    pullSecrets: []
  ## Init Container resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  resources:
    # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
    # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
    # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
    # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
    limits: {}
    #   cpu: 100m
    #   memory: 128Mi
    requests: {}
    #   cpu: 100m
    #   memory: 128Mi
  ## Init container Security Context
  ## Note: the chown of the data folder is done to containerSecurityContext.runAsUser
  ## and not the below volumePermissions.securityContext.runAsUser
  ## When runAsUser is set to special value "auto", init container will try to chwon the
  ## data folder to autodetermined user&group, using commands: `id -u`:`id -G | cut -d" " -f2`
  ## "auto" is especially useful for OpenShift which has scc with dynamic userids (and 0 is not allowed).
  ## You may want to use this volumePermissions.securityContext.runAsUser="auto" in combination with
  ## podSecurityContext.enabled=false,containerSecurityContext.enabled=false and shmVolume.chmod.enabled=false
  ##
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0

## Prometheus Exporter / Metrics
##
metrics:
  enabled: true
  ## Bitnami MongoDB Promtheus Exporter image
  ## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb-exporter/tags/
  ##
  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/mongodb-exporter
    tag: 0.11.1-debian-10-r32
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
    ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
    ##
    # pullSecrets:
    #   - myRegistryKeySecretName

  ## String with extra flags to the metrics exporter
  ## ref: https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter/blob/master/mongodb_exporter.go
  ##
  extraFlags: ""

  ## String with additional URI options to the metrics exporter
  ## ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string
  ##
  extraUri: ""

  ## Metrics exporter container resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  resources:
    # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
    # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
    # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
    # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
    limits: {}
    #   cpu: 100m
    #   memory: 128Mi
    requests: {}
    #   cpu: 100m
    #   memory: 128Mi

  ## Prometheus Exporter service configuration
  ##
  service:
    ## Annotations for Prometheus Exporter pods. Evaluated as a template.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/
    ##
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "{{ .Values.metrics.service.port }}"
      prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 9216

  ## Metrics exporter liveness and readiness probes
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes)
  ##
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 15
    periodSeconds: 5
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 3
    successThreshold: 1
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    failureThreshold: 3
    successThreshold: 1

  ## Prometheus Service Monitor
  ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator
  ##      https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md
  ##
  serviceMonitor:
    ## If the operator is installed in your cluster, set to true to create a Service Monitor Entry
    enabled: true
    ## Specify the namespace where Prometheus Operator is running
    ##
    # namespace: monitoring

    ## Specify the interval at which metrics should be scraped
    ##
    interval: 30s
    ## Specify the timeout after which the scrape is ended
    ##
    # scrapeTimeout: 30s
    ## Used to pass Labels that are used by the Prometheus installed in your cluster to select Service Monitors to work with
    ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#prometheusspec
    ##
    additionalLabels: {}

  ## Custom PrometheusRule to be defined
  ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator#customresourcedefinitions
  ##
  prometheusRule:
    enabled: false
    additionalLabels: {}
    ## Specify the namespace where Prometheus Operator is running
    ##
    # namespace: monitoring
    ## Define individual alerting rules as required
    ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#rulegroup
    ##      https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/
    ##
    rules: {}
```

Comment: Could you check the targets in your prometheus dashboard to see if the metrics are being obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing prometheus using the *"prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack"* helm chart could be quite an extensive topic in itself considering the fact that it has a lot of configurable options.

As the helm chart comes with "prometheus operator", we have used PodMonitor and/or ServiceMonitor CRD's as they provide far more configuration options. Here's some [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#include-servicemonitors) around that.

We've installed it with setting `"prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelector.matchLabels"` with a label value. Something like this

```
serviceMonitorSelector:
  matchLabels:
    monitoring-platform: core-prometheus
```

As for mongodb helm chart, install it `"metrics.enabled=true", "metrics.serviceMonitor.enabled=true" & "metrics.serviceMonitor.additionalLabels"` set to value similar to the label defined in prometheus serviceMonitorSelector (`monitoring-platform: core-prometheus` in this case). Something like this:

```
metrics:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    additionalLabels:
      monitoring-platform: core-prometheus
```

This would enable prometheus scrape metrics from mongodb and subsequently show up in Grafana.

[grafana-mongodb-dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYVZy.png)

Comment: Is there a way to check if a service monitor has been created becuase you can see in my mongodb chart that metrics.enabled and metrics.serviceMintor.enabled are arleady set to true

Comment: And in kube-prometheus-stack it says ```    ## ServiceMonitors to be selected for target discovery.
    ## If {}, select all ServiceMonitors
    ##
    serviceMonitorSelector: {}```

because its set to {} i shouldin't need to apply a specific label?

Comment: Yeah, installation of kube-prometheus-stack installs a few CRDs for you including "servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com". You could do a "kubectl get servicemonitors -A" to get list of all servicemonitors in your cluster.

As for "## If {}, select all ServiceMonitors ## serviceMonitorSelector: {}```", I agree it should discover your mongodb servicemonitor as it describes in the chart comments. But for some reason it didn't do for me too when I first used the chart. So I went for the next best option listed right below there in the chart which is to use "matchLabels".

Comment: Did this or any other solution worked for you? Please do mention so that it's helpful to others.

Comment: @Kay for your question regarding `If {}, select all ServiceMonitors`, `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` needs to be set to `false`. Only then the `serviceMonitorSelector` will be actually set to {} as per the condition here: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml#L112

Comment: So are you saying i should set `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues`  to false?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i do appreciate your comments. Ive had to put this on hold as something else has come up. I can't upgrade to the latest version of this stock, because i need to upgrade my k8 version as im still using 1.5. I had just figured it was being i was using an older verison of the stack. Right now ive not had the chance to do that upgrade yet. So this has become blocked, something nice to have but not urgent.

Comment: Because im using an old verison of kube-prometheus-stack to make any changes i need to upgrade my version of k8's. So this is hold right now and im unable to test your answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. I myself had figured this out a day or two ago and did a quick test on minikube. If you look at line 105-114 in the `prometheus.yaml`, you'll understand when you leave `serviceMonitorSelector` set to {} and `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` by default is true, `matchLabels` gets set to `release: {{ $.Release.Name | quote }}` by default. Thus, leaving `serviceMonitorSelector` set to {} and setting `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` to false kicks in the else condition on line 112 and actually sets `serviceMonitorSelector: {}`

Comment: That's when it will monitor all ServiceMonitor resources irrespective of their labels.

Comment: hey,ive finally had the time to setup this up and test it, like you said setting `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` to false im now able to see mongodb in http://localhost:9090/service-discovery. thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy kube-prometheus-stack with helm it will have the default label value of '`release: <your-mongodb-helm-release-name>`'.
So, On MongoDB, you need to set this label value to `"metrics.serviceMonitor.additionalLabels"`.

```
metrics:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    additionalLabels:
      release: <your-mongodb-helm-release-name>
```